# How to validate model of so string can be between 10 and 30 characters, or empty - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-validation

I'm trying to validate incoming JSON using the Required attribute on a model that contains phone numbers.  There are two phone number properties, a Primary (required) and Alternate.  For the Alternate, I want an empty string to be valid, but strings between 1 and 9 characters and more than 30 characters to be invalid.  This does not work:

```
public class PhoneCreateModel
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "PrimaryPhoneNumberRequired",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationMessage))]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 10,
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "PrimaryPhoneNumberFormat",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationMessage))]
    public string Primary { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 10,
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "AlternatePhoneNumberFormat",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationMessage))]
    public string Alternate { get; set; }
}
```

... because it doesn't allow Alternate to be an empty string.  How can I allow it to be an empty string OR between 10-30 characters?

Comment: Unfortunately, the default model binder tries to save empty strings as a `null` on the model itself, whereas you want to consider it an empty string. I've used a custom model binder that changes this behavior; Someone else might post details before I have a chance to look it up and post the relevant info for you...

Comment: There is an extra attribute you can add to handle this: `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]`, depending on what version of the framework you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own validation attribute. It is easier than it seems, just make a class which extends `ValidationAttribute`, and implement your logic in `IsValid` function.

Here's an example: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/custom-data-annotations-or-custom-validation-attributes-in-m/